# Matplotlib with Eclipse PyDev is not plotting

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, matplotlib, plot

I have the following problem when using Matplotlib in Eclipse with PyDev.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn

...

# Plot results
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')

# Plot the price of the SPY ETF
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211,  ylabel='SPY ETF price in $')
bars['Close'].plot(ax=ax1, color='r', lw=2.)

# Plot the equity curve
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, ylabel='Portfolio value in $')
returns['total'].plot(ax=ax2, lw=2.)

fig.show()
```

I left out the calculations in between.
What happens when I run the program is that the Python Launcher starts and then disappears after 1 second.

I tried to solve the problem on Mac OSX and on Ubuntu and in both cases it did not work.

When using IDLE on the other hand it works and it will come out the following output:

[image]

In general the matplotlib works an Eclipse as I get displayed the output of the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

I also set my backend to template in `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc,` to

```
backend : Qt4Agg
```

Maybe someone has an idea why I can not plot this in Eclipse.
Thank you!